# Why do I keep intermittently getting this error message?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While running my script, I get the following error message during a code that creates a dozen plots in ggplot2 as part of an anlaysis:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
  non-finite location and/or size for viewport
```

The error message crashes the code. Interestingly, changing nothing and running the code again will resolve the problem, and it will work just fine. Sometimes, it will crash while creating a different plot.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on why this is happening.

There should be no error, and sometimes it works as expected.

Comment: What version of R and ggplot are you using? Without some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's not going to be easy to give you any specific answer.

Comment: Me too. It seems to only happen while running unit tests and usually goes away after rerunning the code. I'm using R 3.5.2 and ggplot2 3.1.1